# How to set screenshot name to be named correctly so it will be sortable

Tags: macos, mac

As it is the names that are given to screenshots in Mac OSX are not accurately named to be sorted alphabetical (and then numerical).

In the names below you'll see that a screen shot taken at 3PM is ordered before the picture taken at 12PM.

```
Screen Shot 2012-10-10 at 3.05.19 PM.png 
Screen Shot 2012-10-10 at 12.50.15 PM
```

For it to be ordered correctly either 24hr military time needs to be used or the time needs to be 2 digits. IE "3.05.19" needs to be renamed to "03.05.19".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/339706/48078) for a way to change the complete name sequentially. As far as I know, there's no other way (i.e. through the keyboard shortcuts or other than `screencapture`). Let me know if it doesn't work for you or so, I'll happily reopen and we'll figure things out.

Comment: Hi slhck - Thanks for the link but the solutions there don't answer my question. I'd like to keep the name the same but add either a "0" before the time or use military time. Well now that I think about it military time won't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Screenshots use the *Medium* time format you specify in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Times* (with colons replaced by periods as they're invalid in file names). Click *Customize…* and enter a sane value there, and you're good.

[image: Preferences dialog screenshot]

Comment: FWIW, the US 12 hour clock format will never properly sort, even if you add the leading zero. `12.30 AM` is an hour earlier than `[0]1.30 AM`... It's simply a stupid format.

Comment: Also note that even if you set the hour to 24 hour format, it will still show the AM/PM section. So you have to enter the field and backspace to delete it

Comment: Good answer. But you don't have to change the colons to periods. The screenshot filename uses periods even if colons are used in the format. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245771/change-date-time-format-in-the-screen-shot-filename#

Comment: This has since been moved to "Language & Region" -> Advanced -> Times, but otherwise this works.

Answer (score 4):

IN Sys Prefs / Language & Region, set the Time Format to 24 hour clock and the Snapshot names will use 24 hr format, without AM or PM.  They will then sort correctly.

Comment: while the higher voted answer is correct, this one is fundamentally sound.

Answer (score 2):

Update for those of us with newer macbooks:

1. System Preferences > Language & Region > Advanced > Times
2. In the Medium format, change the hour to `00-23` and delete the `AM`

[image]